# Docker Compose: How recreate container on exit

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use Docker Compose to create two instances of a DevOps build agent. The agent is configured to exit when the build job is finished. I would like to recreate the container and start a new instance. I do not want old files to be kept. Is it possible?

I tried to set restart to always. But the container is not recreated

Here is the compose file.

```yaml
services:
  DevOpsBuildAgent1:
    image: devopsbuildagent
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - AZP_AGENT_NAME=Builder 1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4gb
  DevOpsBuildAgent2:
    image: devopsbuildagent
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - AZP_AGENT_NAME=Builder 2
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4gb
```

Comment: Could you please share your docker-compose file?